# This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'SingleDataSet' and 'number' have no overlap ng2chart [angular]

Tags: angular, typescript, for-loop, ng2-charts

Hi all am trying to check that array contains 0 or not if it has 0 then I wanted to add space in place of 0

```
public atDestinationDoughnutChartData: MultiDataSet = [];

 for (let i = 0; i < this.atDestinationDoughnutChartData.length; ++i) {
                    if (this.atDestinationDoughnutChartData[i] == 0 ) {

                        this.atDestinationDoughnutChartData.push(this.atDestinationDoughnutChartData[i]);
                    }}
```

but am getting error condition will always false  as given in the image below please help me to solve it

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5SMe.png)

Comment: What is the type of **this.atDestinationDoughnutChartData**? it looks type mismatch error.

Comment: public atDestinationDoughnutChartData: MultiDataSet = [];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a data type mismatch error. You are comparing type **MultiDataSet** with a type **number**. So, a simple solution is that put **!** before `this.atDestinationDoughnutChartData[i]`. `!this.atDestinationDoughnutChartData[i]` is equivalent to `this.atDestinationDoughnutChartData[i] == 0`.
Code:

```
public atDestinationDoughnutChartData: MultiDataSet = [];
for (let i = 0; i < this.atDestinationDoughnutChartData.length; ++i) {
    if (!this.atDestinationDoughnutChartData[i]) { this.atDestinationDoughnutChartData.push(this.atDestinationDoughnutChartData[i]);}}
```

Comment: I edited my answer hope it will work... (!variable) is equivalent to (variable == 0).

Comment: bro Is there any way to add space to an array

 for (let i = 0; i < this.atDestinationDoughnutChartData.length; ++i) {
                        if (!this.atDestinationDoughnutChartData[i]) {
                            this.atDestinationDoughnutFinalData.push(" ");
                        } else {
                            this.atDestinationDoughnutFinalData.push(this.atDestinationDoughnutChartData[i]);
                        }
                    }

but its not accepting space

Comment: What is the error here? I could not understand you. you are using the same variable for iterating and pushing value i.e this.atDestinationDoughnutChartData, why it is so?

Comment: actually am trying to add space if the array value is zero if test=[0,0,2] then i want to convert it into test =[" "," ",2]

this is my requirement   test=[0,0,2]  into test =[" "," ",2]

Comment: use this code block:

let atDestinationDoughnutChartData: MultiDataSet = [];  
this.atDestinationDoughnutChartData = this.atDestinationDoughnutChartData.map(data: any => {
if (!data) { return data}
}):